# Costomize React Routing with Switch Statement

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, react-router, firebase-authentication

I am building a react app where two different Usergroups sign in (via Firebase).

Each Usergroup needs to get a different Routing. The different groups should share urls but with different content.

To do so I have added a switch statement to routes js.

When I change acctype manually the code works like expected, but I need to change the acctype var out of my firebaseclass in order to route the right person to the right route...

The problem is, that react renders the view before any setter Method can set the acctype variable. I have tried it with callbacks and .done and asnyc as well.

This routes.js exports the components with the variable rut directly into the index.js React.dom.render()

Thank you for your help!

```
import {Route, Router, IndexRedirect, browserHistory} from 'react-
router';
var acctype = 0;
var rut = "";
switch (acctype) {
case 0: //Group0
  rut = (
    <Router history={browserHistory}>

      <Route path="/" component={Blank}>
        <IndexRedirect to="/welcome"/>
        <Route path="welcome" component={Welcome_View}></Route>
        <Route path="login" component={Login_View}></Route>
        <Route path="*" component={fofView}></Route>
      </Route>

    </Router>
  );
  break;

case 1: //Group1
  rut = (
    <Router history={browserHistory}>
      <Route path="/" component={Main}>
        <IndexRedirect to="/uebersicht"/>
        <Route path="uebersicht" component={Uebersicht_KtppView}></Route>

        <Route path="wiki" component={Wiki_KtppView}></Route>
        <Route path="netzwerk" component={Netzwerk_KtppView}></Route>
        <Route path="meineEinrichtung" component={meineEinrichtung_KtppView}></Route>
        <Route path="feedback" component={Feedback_KtppView}></Route>

      </Route>
    </Router>
  );
  break;
case 2: //Group 2
  rut = (
    <Router history={browserHistory}>
      <Route path="/" component={Main}>
        <IndexRedirect to="/main"/>
        <Route path="main" component={MainView}></Route>
        <Route path="minor" component={MinorView}></Route>
      </Route>
    </Router>
  );
  break;
  }
  export default(rut)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found a new idea to solve this problem

the onEnter attribute does the work

It is described in the last tipp

https://scotch.io/tutorials/routing-react-apps-the-complete-guide